# WSO2 GREG : Multi environment Configuration

Tags: wso2-esb

I have set up 2 ESB (uat & dev) with 1 shared registry basically using the following:

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/

I'm having difficulty adding an uat endpoint & finding it within the esb-uat.  If I used

```
<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
    <instanceId>RemoteGreg</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/governance/branches/uat</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Within the registry, would I expect to see a tree '_system/governance/branches/uat' or do I have to create it?

If I use registry's 'Add Endpoint', I can enter Name/Version/Address/Environment. Is the environment 'branch/uat' or just 'uat'?

If I browse the endpoint I get

```
/_system/governance/trunk/endpoints/ep-<name-address data>
```

Its referencing trunk, not a branch, & 'uat' is no where to be seen. I'm obviously missing something pretty basic here. Is there an example of data entry for shared registry?

Comment: I believe the problem is in part related to unsuccessful mounting of the remote Governance Registry. Examination of the logs does not include info statement "EmbeddedRegistryService connected to mount at remote_registry". There are no errors. I definitely have a remote <dbConfig> element and its associated dataSource, which i know is good.

Comment: It transpires the "EmbeddedRegistryService connected to mount at remote_registry" message is only published if the target path actually exists in the registry! I now just have to figure out add branches/uat etc.

Comment: Within Registry, Add Collection under a node facilitates the extension of the tree for example to construct "/_system/governance/branches/uat". i can then use the copy function to copy the existing structure event, repository, trunk to my uat node. I can also change permissions of  uat node, but I can not mount "/_system/governance/branches/uat", whilst "/_system/governance" does mount. Hence the uat node requires unknown specific characteristics - any idea what thay might be?